# Как перенести данные из Google Sheets в БД PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, google-spreadsheet

Всем привет!

У меня есть Гугл Таблица с данными. Мне необходимо взять из нее данные и внести в БД на основе PostgreSQL, то есть необходимо парсить Google Sheets и перемещать полученные оттуда данные в БД. С БД я еще не работал, поэтому такое задание вызывает определенные сложности. Плюс ко всему, мне надо парсить еще сайт один и оттуда данные тоже добавлять в еще одну колонку БД. Как решить данную проблему? Объясните новичку, пожалуйста, как правильно работать с СУБД, как всё связать воедино?

Заранее спасибо!

P.s.: Питон с Гугл шитс уже связал, т.е. получать данные оттуда могу, вопрос - как их в БД сунуть.

Answer (score 0):

Я успешно переносил из GS в PG вот этим способом: https://hevodata.com/learn/google-sheets-to-postgresql/#method2

Comment: Спасибо! Посмотрю!